# Laravel 5.8 Form updation results in blank page and submitting data showing in address bar

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I am working with simple laravel form . I am not able to update the form as submitting form data is showing in address bar and not entering to controller function.Not able to find any issues in code. Tried all these solutions but no luck. Thanks for any help.

web.php

```
   Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('auth.login');
   });

   Auth::routes();
   Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
     Route::group(['middleware' => 'superadmin'], function () {
      Route::resource('departments', 'DepartmentController');
   });
```

edit.blade.php

```
   <form id="deptform" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action=" 
           {{route('departments.update',$department->id)}}" method="patch">
                 @csrf
                 @method('PATCH')
                  <div class="item form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="dept_name"> Department Name <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 ">
                      <input type="text" id="name" required="required" class="form-control " name="dept_name" value="{{ $department->dept_name }}">
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                  <div class="item form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 offset-md-3">
                      <button class="btn btn-dark" type="reset">Reset</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>

        </form>
```

Department Controller

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{  

   $validatedData = $request->validate([
      'dept_name' => 'required|unique:departments,dept_name,'.$id.',id|max:190'
    ]);
    $department = Department::findOrFail($id);
     $form_data = array(
        'dept_name' =>   $request->dept_name,

    );
     $department->update($form_data);
     return redirect('/departments')->with('success', 'Department is updated successfully ');

}
```

[image: On submiting the address bar will like]

Comment: Check your laravel log file for detailed error

Comment: try adding manual url action form `action="/departements/{{$department->id}}"`

Comment: @Hatchwald. I tried your answer also but didn't work. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed

```
   <form action="{{ route('departments.update',$department->id) }}"method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
   .......

   </form
```